# MiKTeX in R - how can I align the resulting equations

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am using MiKTeX in R. Using this code,

```
$$
1 - p(X) = 1 - \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}} \\

&= \frac{1 + \mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}} - \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}} \\

&= \frac{1 + \mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X} - \mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}} \\

&= \frac{1}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}}
$$
```

Result:

[image]
How can I align the resulting equations to the '=' lines up for each line?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a

```
\begin{align*}
  ...
\end{align*}
```

construction, placing an `&` to the left of every `=`:

```
When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:
\begin{align*}
1 - p(X) &= 1 - \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}} \\
&= \frac{1 + \mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}} - \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}} \\
&= \frac{1 + \mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X} - \mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}} \\
&= \frac{1}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 X}}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Also, you can't have any blank lines inside `align*` in general.